# CakePHP check or add user id to posts

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following two actions in my controller:

```
function add()
    {
        if (!empty($this->data))
        {
            if ($this->Favour->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your favour has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
    }

    function edit($id = null)
    {
        $this->Favour->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data))
        {
            $this->data = $this->Favour->read();
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->Favour->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your favour has been updated.');
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**1)** I want to be able to add the logged in user id to the add action so that the new post is created with that user as its author id (their is a foreign key in the db table). I'm not sure how to talk to fields within the controller itself.

**2)** And for the edit action I want to make it so that only the author can edit the post so for example user 200 creates post 20 but user 100 cannot edit this post because his id is not 200! I'm not using ACL for my app but just simple authentication.

I've thought about doing a simple if statement in the action like:

```
function edit($id = null)
    {
        $this->Favour->id = $id;
        $this->Favour->user_id = $user_id;

        if($this->Auth->user('id') != $user_id)
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You do not have permission to edit that favour!');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            if (empty($this->data))
            {
                $this->data = $this->Favour->read();
            }
            else
            {
                if ($this->Favour->save($this->data))
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your favour has been updated.');
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'index'));
                }
            }
        }
```

Would this be correct? **BUT how do I get the user id from the favour?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data['Favour']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Favour->save($this->data)) {
            //etc
```

This code assumes:

- Your user is logged in
- the user can access the `add` function
- You are storing the `id` value of the logged in user in the field `id`
- You have a foreign key in `Favours` table called `user_id` that matches the data type of the user `id`

As for edit; couple ways of achieving it.
I'd do:

```
function edit($id) {
    $this->Favour->id = $id;
    $favour_author = $this->Favour->field('user_id'); 
    // get the user of this post

    if($this->Auth->user('id') != $favour_author) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You do not own this post.');
        $this->redirect('/someplace');
    }

    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Favour->read();
    }
        // carry on.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Auth Component, you can access the logged-in user record in $this->Auth->user() in controller. So to access the id:  $this->Auth->user('id'). If you write your own authentication, it's up to you.

```
how to talk to fields within the controller itself.
```

What do you mean?

Comment: I mean how would I insert data into a field that isn't in the view such as the `user_id` foreign key in the favour table?

Comment: $this->data['Favour']['user_id'] before $this->Favour->save($this->data)

Comment: But how do I put that data in? As that will just say where to put the data but not what the data is...